# Alternatives to np.newaxis() for saving memory when comparing arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to copared each vector from one array with all vectors from another array, and count how many symbols matches per vector. Let me show an example.
I have two arrays, *a* and *b*. 
For each vector in *a*, I want to compare it with each vector in *b*. I then want to return a new array which is with dimension `np.array((len(a),14))` where each vector holds the number of times vectors in *a* had 0,1,2,3,4,..,12,13 matches with vectors from *b*. The wished results are shown in array *c* below.

I already have solved this problem using `np.newaxis()` but my issue is (see my function below), that this takes up so much memory so my computer can't handle it when *a* and *b* gets larger. Hence, I am looking for a more efficient way to do this calculation, as it hurts my memory big time to add on dimensions to the vectors. One solution is to go with a normal for loop, but this method is rather slow.

Is it possible to make these calculations more efficient?

```
a = array([[1., 1., 1., 2., 1., 1., 2., 1., 0., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
           [0., 2., 2., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 2., 1., 2.],
           [0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 2., 1., 2., 0., 1., 2., 2.],
           [1., 2., 2., 0., 1., 1., 0., 2., 0., 1., 1., 0., 2.],
           [1., 2., 0., 2., 2., 0., 2., 0., 0., 1., 2., 0., 0.]])

b = array([[0., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 2., 2.],
           [1., 0., 1., 2., 2., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 2., 1., 2.],
           [1., 2., 1., 2., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 2., 2., 0., 2.],
           [0., 1., 2., 0., 2., 1., 0., 1., 2., 0., 0., 0., 2.],
           [0., 2., 2., 1., 2., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 2., 2., 2.],
           [0., 2., 2., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 2., 2., 1.],
           [1., 0., 2., 2., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 2., 2.],
           [1., 1., 0., 2., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 2., 0., 2., 2.],
           [1., 2., 0., 0., 0., 1., 2., 1., 0., 1., 2., 0., 1.],
           [1., 2., 1., 2., 2., 1., 2., 0., 2., 0., 0., 1., 1.]])

c = array([[0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 3, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 1, 1, 4, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

My solution:

```
def new_method_test(a,b):
    test = (a[:,np.newaxis] == b).sum(axis=2)
    zero     = (test == 0).sum(axis=1)
    one      = (test == 1).sum(axis=1)
    two      = (test == 2).sum(axis=1)
    three    = (test == 3).sum(axis=1)
    four     = (test == 4).sum(axis=1)
    five     = (test == 5).sum(axis=1)
    six      = (test == 6).sum(axis=1)
    seven    = (test == 7).sum(axis=1)
    eight    = (test == 8).sum(axis=1)
    nine     = (test == 9).sum(axis=1)
    ten      = (test == 10).sum(axis=1)
    eleven   = (test == 11).sum(axis=1)
    twelve   = (test == 12).sum(axis=1)
    thirteen = (test == 13).sum(axis=1)
    c = np.concatenate((zero,one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,ten,eleven,twelve,thirteen), axis = 0).reshape(14,len(a)).T
    return c
```

Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to Stackoverflow! I think a for loop is the way to go if you want to save memory (and it's really not that slow). Additionally you can directly go from one test to your c output matrix with [np.bincount](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html). I think this method will be approximately equally fast as yours and it will use significantly less memory by comparison.

```
import numpy as np
c = np.empty(a.shape, dtype=int)
for i in range(a.shape[0]):
    test_one_vector = (a[i,:]==b).sum(axis=1)
    c[i,:] = np.bincount(test_one_vector, minlength=a.shape[1])
```

---

Small sidenote if you are really dealing with floating point numbers in a and b you should consider dropping the equality check (==) in favor of a proximity check like e.g. [np.isclose](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html)

Comment: Thank you! And thank for you solution. I actually made a solution with a for loop myself. However, i didn't use the np.bincount(). It decreases my runtimes many folds! Amazing, thank you :)